# Audit & Telemetry in MS DYNAMICS CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, reporting, microsoft-dynamics, auditing

Is there any possible way to get advanced auditing options in crm dynamics (third party tool, querying database filteredviews)

I want to know Number of user connected, duration of connection for each user, time passed in each form, reports executed(by who).

Comment: Yes, there is auditing in CRM. Check this article: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmlessons/archive/2011/03/29/crm-2011-auditing-best-practices If it is on premise and you can query SQL you have those tools at your disposal as well.

Comment: If you want this level of detail, you probably need tracking like Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked for 2 different things.

**Auditing:**

CRM OOB auditing data stored in on-premise SQL is "`,`" and "`~`" separated, so have to do reverse engineering & some Power BI chart will visualize nicely on top of the data. We did that by referring below link.
https://marcuscrast.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/dynamics-crm-2011-audit-report-in-ssrs/

**Telemetry:**

Custom solution using application insights can be collected, including your own metrics like explained in my blog post below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-sample-mscrm

On a side note, CRM 2016 has a preview feature of Organization Insights which will cover few of your asks. Refer the link below.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt703628.aspx

Comment: For 3rd party tools, search the internet.

Comment: Thank you Arun those links are very helpful..can i use the application insight for dynamics 2015 on premise?

Comment: Yes, you need Azure subscription & internet access (why am saying this - banking domain will not have)